# How to set random movement direction of koning(ghost in pacman) and how to make the coins to disappear in pacman game using tKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

We are creating pacman in Python- tKinter(not in pygame) and the coins are not disappearing. I am not able to finish the program of random movement of koning(ghost).

It is supposed to change direction every 10 steps and not go out of the canvas. The coins are supposed to disappear after the pacman goes through the coin, it would disappear. The coins are supposed to be counted and be shown in the corner. After the 3 times the pacman meets the ghost, it would print ;Game over;.

````
sirka = 0
vyska = 0
koning_x = 0
koning_y = 0

```pome=coins
pome_x = 0
pome_y = 0

random_direction = random.randint(0,3)
counter = 10
def platne_pole (y, x) :
    global sirka
    global vyska
    if (x > 0 and x < sirka - 1) and (y > 0 and y < vyska - 1):
        return True
    return False
def kmove (event):
    global koning_x
    global koning_y
    global mapa
    target_x = koning_x *cell_size
    target_y = koning_y *cell_size
    def posun (target_x, target_y, koning_smer):
        if koning_smer == 0:
            target_y -= 1
        elif koning_smer == 1:
            target_x += 1
        elif koning_smer == 2:
            target_y += 1
        elif koning_smer == 3:
            target_x == 1
        return target_x, target_y
        target_x, target_y = kmove(koning_x, koning_y, koning_smer)
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code is not formatted properly. Please look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks to help people understand the code you have written so far. Also the code after your return statement is never executed. Is your indentation correct?

Comment: Thank you, that's because I'm not able to continue as I am not sure how...